# How to set controllers in view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, stack, swiftui

I'm having a problem with set `Image` and `Text`. I would like to have `Image` on top of the view, then have a break and put several `Text` controls one below the other, but everytime my `Image` is almost on the center of the View. Where is the problem? Below is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScanWithPhotoFromLibrary: View {

    @State var cupWidth: String = ""
    @State var cupHeight: String = ""
    @State var stemLength: String = ""
    @State var leafWidth: String = ""
    @State var leafLength: String = ""

    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    @State private var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera

    @State private var userImage: UIImage?
    @State private var flowerName: String = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var env: ImagePickerCoordinator

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{

            ZStack{

                VStack(){
                    GeometryReader { geo in
                        Image(uiImage: self.userImage ?? UIImage(named: "flower_logo")!)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio( contentMode:.fill)
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 350)
                    }

                    Spacer()

                    Text("Enter dimensions in centimeters [cm]")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.system(size:22))

                    HStack(alignment: .top){
                        Text("Cup width: ")
                            .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { d in d[.trailing] })
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                        TextField("0.00", text: $cupWidth)
                            .font(.system(size:20))
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }.padding(.horizontal, 30)


                }
            }

        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(flowerName).foregroundColor(.blue), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                HStack {
                    Button("Library") {
                        self.showImagePicker = true
                        self.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                        print("Library tapped!")
                       }
                   }
           )
           .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
               ImagePicker(image: self.$userImage, isShown: self.$showImagePicker, flowerName: self.$flowerName, sourceType: self.sourceType)

           }
       }
}

struct ScanWithPhotoFromLibrary_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScanWithPhotoFromLibrary()
    }
}
```

At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: There is a lot of code here that is not relevant to the question. Next time you may want to [provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The GeometryReader is consuming all available space. A resizable Image will try to fit in the available space by default, so if you set the height of its frame, GeometryReader is not necessary. You'll probably want to use content mode fit instead of fill as well. I also don't see why you would want to ignore the safe area edges here; this is a logo, not a background and it should probably not be obscured by a notch.

```
VStack {

    Image(uiImage: self.userImage ?? UIImage(named: "flower_logo")!)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode:.fit)
        .frame(height: 350)

    Spacer()

    Text("Enter dimensions in centimeters [cm]")
        .bold()
        .font(.system(size:22))

    ...
}
```